# how to remove outliers based on standard dev, using tidyverse?

Tags: r, dplyr, inner-join, tidyverse, outliers

I tried out this code using tidyverse package to filter outliers based on sd.

```
rt_trimmed_data_Dec = data_Dec %>%
 group_by(Time_of_Testing, Item_Type, Group) %>%
 summarise(RT_mean = mean(RT, na.rm=TRUE), RT_sd = sd(RT, na.rm=TRUE))%>%
 ungroup()  %>%
 mutate(rt_high = RT_mean + (2.5 * RT_sd)) %>%
  mutate(rt_low = RT_mean - (2.5 * RT_sd))
```

Then, I tried to join the two data frames, to apply the filtering out.

```
data_Dec_RT = data_Dec %>%
   inner_join(rt_trimmed_data_Dec) %>%
   filter(RT < rt_high) %>%
    filter(RT > rt_low)
```

But then I got this error

> ```
> Error: `by` required, because the data sources have no common variables
> ```
>
> Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace. > rlang::last_error()
>   
>   message: `by` required, because the data sources have no common variables
>   class:   `rlang_error`
>   backtrace:
>     1. dplyr::inner_join(., rt_trimmed_data_Dec)
>     9. dplyr:::common_by.NULL(by, x, y)
>    11. dplyr:::bad_args("by", "required, because the data sources have no common variables")
>    12. dplyr:::glubort(fmt_args(args), ..., .envir = .envir)
>    13. dplyr::inner_join(., rt_trimmed_data_Dec).

Could you please advise on how to solve this issue, I would highly appreciate your help.

Comment: Where are you merging?? There are no common columns (with same name) and you do not define them either. How is R supposed to know where to merge?

Comment: Make sure `rt_trimmed_data_Dec` has columns common with `data_Dec`, otherwise, define `by` in `inner_join` with the columns you want to use from both data frames. See `?inner_join` for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can do this with

```
library(dplyr)
data_Dec %>%
  group_by(Time_of_Testing, Item_Type, Group) %>%
  filter(between(RT, mean(RT, na.rm=TRUE) - (2.5 * sd(RT, na.rm=TRUE)), 
                     mean(RT, na.rm=TRUE) + (2.5 * sd(RT, na.rm=TRUE))))
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help Ronak, the code worked fine. So, does the code worked in a similar but faster way, to the one I had:  filter(RT < rt_high) %>%
    filter(RT > rt_low) ? Thanks again for your contribution.

Comment: @azizitamimi You don't need to use `filter` twice. You can combine the two `filter` conditions together. Also I avoid creating new columns with `summarise` and then joining which makes it faster.

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty easy to do by z scoring your RT column using *scale*.

```
    library(tidyverse)

    samples = 50
    Ps = 10

    # data frame that contains participant numbers, and RT scores
    data <- data.frame(participant = as.factor(rep(1:Ps, each = samples)),
                       RT = rnorm(n = samples*Ps, mean = 600, sd = 50))

    data_noOutliers <- data %>% 
      group_by(participant) %>% 
      mutate(zRT = scale(RT)) %>% 
      filter(between(zRT,-2.5,+2.5))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your conurbation Tom. I was not aware that scale() can do that. It is much faster and makes more sense than the code I had. So, in my report can I say that outliers were removed based on the SD values, or based on Z scores?

Comment: The z score is a standardised version of the RT, where +1 is a value 1SD above the mean. Therefore you can remove on the basis of zRT that is above and below 2.5. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clarifications Tom, I highly appreciate it.